# Inequality reversing with trigonometric function.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

We are given that $\arg(z-1) \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$, where $z$ is a complex number. When trying to shade this region, I let $z=x+iy \implies$ arg$[(x-1)+i(y)] \leq \frac{3\pi}{4} \implies \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x-1}) \leq \frac{3\pi}{4} $

I know $ \tan(\frac{3\pi}{4}) = -1,$ and I had guessed that the inequality will need to be flipped to result in: $\frac{y}{x-1} \geq -1$, but I am not sure why. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

More simply we can proceed as follows

- at first consider the region for $w=z-1$ such that $\arg(w) \leq \frac{3\pi}4$,
- then we can apply a translation for $z=w+1$.

Using $\arctan$ we need to pay attention since the function has range in $\left(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right)$.

Comment: i still don't understand why the inequality reverses in direction.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If we interpret the inequality description for the region in more of a "pre-calculus" setting, the specification that the argument of $ \ z - 1 \ $ be less than $ \ \frac{3 \pi}{4} \ $ requires points representing $ \ z \ $ to lie "on or above" the $ \ x-$axis ( $ \mathfrak{Re}(z) $ ) axis (shaded in red in the graph above) *and* "on or above" the line of slope $ \ -1 \ $ ( $  \tan \frac{3 \pi}{4}  $  ) passing through the point $ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ \   $ (shaded in blue).  The region so described then appears in purple, excluding of course the point $ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ \   $ itself (for which the argument is undefined).

So the region in question satisfies $ \ y \ \ge \ 0 \ \ \wedge \ \ y \ \ge \ -1·(x - 1) \ = \ 1 - x \ \   $ [omitting  $ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ ] \ . \   $  We have $ \  x \ > \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ y \ \ge \ 0 \ > \ 1 - x \ \ , \ $ thus the region includes all points "on or above" the real axis (for $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ we exclude the point *on* that axis).  For $ \ x \ < \ 1 \ , \ $ however, the chain inequality becomes $ \ 0 \ < \ 1 - x \ \le \ y \ \ . \ $  With both of these quantities positive, we can perform the division to obtain
$ \ 1 \ \le \ \frac{y}{1 \ - \ x} \ \ ; \ $ multiplying this inequality through by $ \ -1 \ \ $ produces  $ \ -1 \ \ge \ \frac{y}{x \ - \ 1} \ \ . \ $

The inequality you produced is not correct (you perhaps confused yourself in your algebraic manipulation).  Consider, for instance, $ \ z \ = \ -2 + 6i \ \ : \ $ we then have the ratio $ \ \frac{y}{x \ - \ 1} \ = \ \frac{6}{(-2) \ - \ 1} \ = \ -2 \ \ . \ $   For $ \ x \ < \ 1 \ \ , \ $ this ratio needs to be *more* negative than $ \ -1 \ \  $ (the ray from $ \ 1 + 0i \ $ to $ \ -2 + 6i \ $ having a *more steeply negative* slope)  .  The inequality as you have written it  lets the ratio be *less* negative than $ \ -1 \ \ , \ $ or even *positive* (which would then require $ \ y \ $ to be negative, contradicting the condition $ \ y \ \ge \ 0 \ ) \ .  $